# How can I tell if I'm viewing a secure page in Safari (6.0.2)?

Tags: macos, safari, security

Safari hides the http: or https:, so how can I tell if I'm viewing a page over SSL? Some pages show issuer information in the URL bar, but not all of them. So the ones that show issuer info are secure, but I'd rather not have to reload the other pages in Chrome just to determine whether I have a secure connection to it.

Comment: You can also see the full URL by pressing ⌘LCV.

Comment: Excellent question. And concerning everyone and other web browser like Firefox.
Hence I added a security tag to this question.

Comment: This http versus https indication in raw was one of the unique trustable indicator for a normal user. All the other tricks can't be trusted since they basically "hide" the truth.

Comment: For excellent reasons, Apple decided to bring back this textual security information. This is a very good point since this text field can't easily be messed up. This text field is the simplest and strongest validation that a connection is actually `http` versus `https`.

Comment: Firefox doesn't yet receive enough user feedback to see the path ☹.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On safari open Inspector->Resource Tab-> on right hand panel you can see Scheme: will be HTTPS if https or HTTP if secure.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

On HTTPS pages Safari shows a small padlock.

[image] (screen made with Safari 6.0.2)

You can see this a little easier in these larger snaps - one of a site where the SSL certificate was not trusted implicitly (signed or otherwise trusted by your Mac) and another where the certificate was valid and signed up the chain by the Mac and shown in green.

[image: Unknown SSL certificate in Safari]
[image: Good SSL certificate in Safari]

Comment: It seems to me like not all https pages show that. I'll try to find a specific example site.

Comment: The problem with blanket statements about https is that there is no standard for what part of a page should/must/is sent encrypted and which is not. This might make an interesting follow on question as to why one site shows secure on when another is off and where safari currently draws the line on showing a badge in the address bar.

Comment: the padlock does not show up on https://bundio.com, for example.  This site has the standard ssl certificate from go daddy.  The different flavors of ssl may show differently on safari.  ⌘LCV shows the entire url with https.

Answer (score 5):

Some pages will display the lock icon during loading, then it will disappear.  This is because there is some insecure content on the page, for example Google AdSense ads on a secure page can cause this.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to the answer by @chrisg I recently noticed that some Safari Extensions will also hide the lock icon, presumably because they send or receive information over http. So if you are having problems when no site will show the padlock, lock through your Extensions...

(I know this question is a bit old, but I thought this might be valuable information)

Answer (score 1):

In response to Matthieu post, the https or EV Disclosure is only visible when the page initially loads, once finished it hides it again which is really annoying. The only way to  show it i've found so far is Lauri answer by pressing ⌘LCV which is nuts. If im paying for an EV I want my customers to see it!

Comment: Please post an example of this behavior. When I visit the [Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/), the HTTPS icon in the address bar does not disappear after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to @Fredrik -- the lack of an *encryption button* (padlock icon) on a site accessed using HTTPS may indicate that one or more extensions are out of date (check Safari->Preferences->Extensions).

Answer (score -1):

Or, just tap the address bar and the whole address is shown.
Including the https:

Comment: This is referring to Safari in iOS, whereas the question was specifically about Safari in OS X. Clicking (tapping) the address bar in OS X does *not* show the whole address.